# Does PDFBox allow to remove one field from AcroForm?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using Apache [PDFBox 2.0.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.8)  and trying to remove one field. But can not find the way to do it, like I can do with iText:     `PdfStamper.getAcroFields().removeField("signature3")`.

What I am tying to do. Initially I have template PDF with 3 Digital Signatures. In some cases I need just 2 signatures, so it this case I need to remove 3rd signature from the template. And seems like I can't do it with PDFBox, close thing I found is flattening this field, but that problem is if a flatten particular PDField (not whole form, but just one field) - all other signatures are loosing their functionality, looks like they are getting flattened as well.
Here is code that does it:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
PDDocumentCatalog documentCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = documentCatalog.getAcroForm();

List<PDField> flattenList = new ArrayList<>();
for (PDField field : acroForm.getFieldTree()) {
    if (field instanceof PDSignatureField && "signature3".equals(field.getFullyQualifiedName())) {
        flattenList.add(field);
    }
}

acroForm.flatten(flattenList, true);
document.save(dest);        
document.close();
```

Comment: So... you're asking a PdfBox question, but you're tagging it as an iText question? Can you explain why you did that?

Comment: If you don't want to explain, people will make assumptions about your motives. Those assumptions won't be positive.

Comment: To clarify: I assume that you're opposed to free software, and that you only want software that is *for free* because you don't value developers and their work. You have no idea about [the realities of being a FOSS maintainer](https://caddy.community/t/the-realities-of-being-a-foss-maintainer/2728), because you're a [software cannibal](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:chapter6#Eat-Me). That assumption may be wrong, but since you don't feel like explaining, that's what I'm guessing.

Comment: If a question is wrongly tagged, it takes less effort to remove the wrong tag than to write 3 comments to complain about it.

Comment: Do you mean empty signature fields? Can you share the template PDF? PDFBox doesn't have a method to remove a field from the field tree but it might be possible anyway if the tree structure is simple.

Comment: Hi, Tilman, my PDfF very simple, all my signatures are as root fields. I was thinking about manipulating tree structure, but I did not go further with that when I saw that getChildren() method in PDFBox is returning new instance of the list, but the actual list: List<PDField> children = new ArrayList<PDField>(); But mkl below went further and extended your idea. Thanks for it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Tilman already mentioned in a comment, *PDFBox doesn't have a method to remove a field from the field tree.* Nonetheless it has methods to manipulate the underlying PDF structure, so one can write such a method oneself, e.g. like this:

```
PDField removeField(PDDocument document, String fullFieldName) throws IOException {
    PDDocumentCatalog documentCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = documentCatalog.getAcroForm();

    if (acroForm == null) {
        System.out.println("No form defined.");
        return null;
    }

    PDField targetField = null;

    for (PDField field : acroForm.getFieldTree()) {
        if (fullFieldName.equals(field.getFullyQualifiedName())) {
            targetField = field;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (targetField == null) {
        System.out.println("Form does not contain field with given name.");
        return null;
    }

    PDNonTerminalField parentField = targetField.getParent();
    if (parentField != null) {
        List<PDField> childFields = parentField.getChildren();
        boolean removed = false;
        for (PDField field : childFields)
        {
            if (field.getCOSObject().equals(targetField.getCOSObject())) {
                removed = childFields.remove(field);
                parentField.setChildren(childFields);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!removed)
            System.out.println("Inconsistent form definition: Parent field does not reference the target field.");
    } else {
        List<PDField> rootFields = acroForm.getFields();
        boolean removed = false;
        for (PDField field : rootFields)
        {
            if (field.getCOSObject().equals(targetField.getCOSObject())) {
                removed = rootFields.remove(field);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!removed)
            System.out.println("Inconsistent form definition: Root fields do not include the target field.");
    }

    removeWidgets(targetField);

    return targetField;
}

void removeWidgets(PDField targetField) throws IOException {
    if (targetField instanceof PDTerminalField) {
        List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = ((PDTerminalField)targetField).getWidgets();
        for (PDAnnotationWidget widget : widgets) {
            PDPage page = widget.getPage();
            if (page != null) {
                List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
                boolean removed = false;
                for (PDAnnotation annotation : annotations) {
                    if (annotation.getCOSObject().equals(widget.getCOSObject()))
                    {
                        removed = annotations.remove(annotation);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!removed)
                    System.out.println("Inconsistent annotation definition: Page annotations do not include the target widget.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Widget annotation does not have an associated page; cannot remove widget.");
                // TODO: In this case iterate all pages and try to find and remove widget in all of them
            }
        }
    } else if (targetField instanceof PDNonTerminalField) {
        List<PDField> childFields = ((PDNonTerminalField)targetField).getChildren();
        for (PDField field : childFields)
            removeWidgets(field);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Target field is neither terminal nor non-terminal; cannot remove widgets.");
    }
}
```

*([RemoveField](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/RemoveField.java#L172) helper methods `removeField` and `removeWidgets`)*

One can apply this to a document and field like this:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(SOURCE_PDF);

PDField field = removeField(document, "Signature1");
Assert.assertNotNull("Field not found", field);

document.save(TARGET_PDF);        
document.close();
```

*([RemoveField](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/RemoveField.java#L160) test `testRemoveInvisibleSignature`)*

---

**PS:** I am not sure how much form related information PDFBox actually caches somewhere. Thus, I would propose not to manipulate the form information any further in the same document manipulation session, at least not without tests.

**PPS:** You find a TODO in the `removeWidgets` helper method. If the method outputs *"Widget annotation does not have an associated page; cannot remove widget"*, you'll have to add the missing code.

Comment: Thank you very much, mkl! That is awesome idea to reset children! Great implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mkl, I managed to do so with a shorter implementation using version pdfbox-3.0.0-RC1. in this case, to hide a button (check):

```
        var check = (PDPushButton) pdAcroForm.getField(name);
    List<PDField> fields = pdAcroForm.getFields();
    fields.removeIf(x -> x.getCOSObject().equals(check.getCOSObject()));
    pdAcroForm.setFields(fields);
    check.getWidgets().forEach(widget -> widget.setNoView(true));
```

Comment: Note that this might run into trouble if the fields are arranged in a tree structure; `getFields()` returns a flattened view, and you're setting the flattened/filtered view as the new value.

Comment: `widget.setNoView(true)` only hides the widget for purposes of on-screen display and user interaction. It does not remove it, though. Depending on a PDF processor's approach to finding fields, therefore, such a processor may run into issues with your file, finding widgets of form fields which are not reachable from the document form definition.

Answer (score 0):

My Kotlin/PDFBox 3.0.0 solution, fwiw:

```
fun removeField(field: PDField) {
    field.parent?.run {
        this.children = children.withoutField(field)
    }
    field.takeIf { it.parent == null }?.run {
        acroForm.fields = acroForm.fields.withoutField(field)
    }
    field.widgets.forEach { it.isNoView = true }
}

private fun MutableList<PDField>.withoutField(field: PDField): MutableList<PDField> {
    removeIf { it.cosObject == field.cosObject && it.fullyQualifiedName == field.fullyQualifiedName }
    return this
}
```

Probably not necessary to check both cosObject and fullyQualifiedName for equality I guess.

Comment: Setting `it.isNoView = true` only hides the widget for purposes of on-screen display and user interaction. It does _not_ remove it, though. Depending on a PDF processor's approach to finding fields, therefore, such a processor may run into issues with your file, finding widgets of form fields which are not reachable from the document form definition.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Honestly, that approach was just copied from the other post here, so it wasn't really thought through on my part. Do you know how I could solve it instead?

Comment: Well, have a look at my old answer here which in `removeWidgets` removes the widget annotation from the annotation array of the associated page. But even there is a ToDo left open for cases in which the page information is missing. In that case you have to iterate over all pages and remove.