# java PDFBox : remove Signature field and widget

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to remove an existing signature field (PDSignatureField) from a PDF document and its associated widget (PDAnnotationWidget)

I am using the code provided by the following answer :

[Does PDFBox allow to remove one field from AcroForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190189/does-pdfbox-allow-to-remove-one-field-from-acroform)

I am actually able to retrieve both of the field and the associated widget, and I remove them from the PDDocument (remove the field from AcroForm, remove the widget from page annotations)

As my process needs to use the incremental save, I update the acroFrom and the page COSObjects as follow :

`acroForm.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);`

`page.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);`

But after saving it, the document still seem to contain the deleted widget... Even though the field seems to be deleted. Can anybody help me out on this ? Is it a good way to do it ?

EDIT :

This is my problem :

```
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            List<PDAnnotation> annotations = document.getPage(i).getAnnotations();
   }
}
```

Here, the "annotations" list returns a not empty set, although I did remove the annotations before the incremental save.

Thank you

Comment: When you save changes as an incremental update, everything previously in the document remains in there, it merely probably gets hidden. Thus, it is clear that "the document still seem to contain the deleted widget". You might want to explain more exactly what you mean here, maybe it's not as well hidden as you hoped for?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited the post so that you can understand what is my problem when I say the annotations are not deleted.

Comment: I don't see your code as a whole. I assume, though, that you did not `setNeedToBeUpdated(true)` to all necessary objects. In pre-3.0 PDFBox versions a whole path of objects from the catalog to the actually changed objects needs to be marked `setNeedToBeUpdated(true)`, in case of page objects, therefore, in particular a whole path through the page tree to the page in question. Also, if the annotations array is indirect, that object also must be marked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the replies. I managed to solve my problem, as mkl said, I needed to create a path of changed objects.

This is what I did :

```
        COSDictionary dictionary = document.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject();
        dictionary.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
        dictionary = (COSDictionary) dictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.ACRO_FORM);
        dictionary.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
        COSArray array = (COSArray) dictionary.getDictionaryObject(COSName.FIELDS);
        array.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

        // for each changed page
        COSDictionary item = page.getCOSObject();
                
        while (item.containsKey(COSName.PARENT)) {
            COSBase parent = item.getDictionaryObject(COSName.PARENT);
            if (parent instanceof COSDictionary) {
                item = (COSDictionary) parent;
                item.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
            }
        }
                
        page.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
```